# Android layout make only one view draw itself as though its in landscape, but everything else use portrait

Tags: android, layout, orientation

The main view element in the layout for my activity is a VideoView. My video is rendered to the landscape resolution of the device, but all of the content in the video is sideways, so its still meant to be viewed while the device is in the portrait position even though I have to set my activity to `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in my manifest (I have to do that or else the video doesn't take up the full screen). My question is: Is it possible for me to set a parameter on my video view that tells it to use landscape mode but have everything else that happens in my app be oriented for portrait mode? Similar to the `android:orientation="horizontal/vertical"` tag for LinearLayouts.

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried FrameLayouts to divide the landscape portion from the portrait portion??

Comment: Im not sure I know what you mean. Like put the VideoView inside of a FrameLayout by itself? Does frame layout have a parameter that lets me specify orientation=landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: Is it possible for me to set a parameter on my video view that tells it to use landscape mode but have everything else that happens in my app be oriented for portrait mode?

No, sorry.

On Android 3.0, you could try playing around with `android:rotation`, but I fear that this may slow things down tremendously. Plus, of course, it's only on 3.0.