# Play Video only on Landscape - Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application on VideoView...and 
I need to play the video only in landscape mode.
I tried the following code but the entire activity turns on landscape mode. However I need only the videoview in the Xml layout to play in the landscape.

```
<activity android:name=".Video_play"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: Maybe your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500478/android-layout-make-only-one-view-draw-itself-as-though-its-in-landscape-but-ev

Comment: If nothing works then you can **design layout in landscape mode** and change the orientation of your activity using code `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`